# The graph of panel will go after the form is minimized, C#

Tags: c#, graphics, panel

I have a panel in my form named `Pan_Paint` and I have the code below:

```
Graphics graph = Pan_Paint.CreateGraphics();
graph.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Blue), 10, 10, 100, 100);
```

When I minize the form, and the when I restore it, the line will disappear. Or when I press Tab Button, the same thing will happen. What can I do to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: I don't want to draw it again I just want to know is there another way or not. My program is not just the code above it has a lot of shapes in it so I can't draw them again.

Comment: You need to read up on the drawing pipeline... there are many ways you can interact with a window and some of these will force the window to redraw itself, without knowledge of this extra ellipse. So to reiterate what Sneftel said, just draw it again - appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic.

You either need to **cache all drawing** in some data structures and have them drawn in the `Paint` event. Again and again, whenever windows needs to restore the Screen.

You initially call the Paint event by doing an `Panel.Invalidate()` whenever you have added some drawing actions to your drawing queues.

No way around that other than:

Draw them **into** the **Image** of a **PictureBox** (not just onto the PictureBox!)..

Here is the code to do it right with a PictureBox and also how to do it wrong:

```
  // this will change the Image of a PictureBox, assuming it has one.
  // These changes are persistent:

    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
    {
        G.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(0, 0, 444, 444));
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

  // This is the wrong, non-persistent way to paint, no matter which control: 
  //The changes go away whenever the Window is invalidated:

    using (Graphics G = pictureBox2.CreateGraphics() )
    {
        G.DrawEllipse(Pens.Green, new Rectangle(0, 0, 444, 444));
    }
```

Instead create a class of drawing actions and loop over a list of them in the Paint event!

Comment: This works fine for the OP. So: You are drawing onto a Panel which you also want to scroll?  For this you will have to add the correct coordinates. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814849/i-cant-click-at-last-cell-in-table-layout-panel/35816795#35816795) - You will need to ask a question of your own if you can't get it  to work..

Comment: I have upvoted, you are right i haven't mentioned Panel.