# image disappear when i minimize my form, scroll doesn't show

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drag-and-drop, panel

I have writen code below for drag and drop. when I drag an image into my panel it is added, but when i minimize the form it disappears.(it is a C# windows form application)
**1st:** What's the reason of that?
**2nd:** How can I fix it?
I set panel1 auto scroll property and allow drop to true, but when image is bigger than form size scroll doesn't appear.
**3rd:** How can i fix problem with scroll?

```
private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
}

private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] imagePath =(string[]) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
    g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(imagePath[0]), new Point(0, 0));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of among many many others [The graph of panel will go after the form is minimized, C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884022/the-graph-of-panel-will-go-after-the-form-is-minimized-c-sharp)

Comment: You will have to cache not 'Draw Actions' but the filename, of course. Or go for a PictureBox.  For scrollbars to appear not the image but the panel must be larger than the form. Also look up the trick of nesting a Panel (or a PictureBox) in a Panel. The nested Control is sized to show the full size of the image, the outer set to Autoscroll.

Comment: Could you solve your problems?

Comment: No, i already can use picture box but i was trying to use image drawing and it seems that it can't be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to display an image file is to load it into a PictureBox. That way you don't have to worry about persisting it by redrawing it.

To accomplish this you simply change your code to

```
string[] imagePath;

private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  imagePath = (string[]) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
  if (imagePath.Length > 0 )   pictureBox1.ImageLocation = imagePath[0];
}
```

You may want to add error handling to catch wrong file types.

To address scrolling you place the PictureBox **inside** the Panel and script the `LoadCompleted` event:

```
private void pictureBox1_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.ClientSize = pictureBox1.Image.Size;
}
```

The Panel needs to have set `AutoScroll` to true, the PictureBox should sit at `Location` 0;0 and have `SizeMode` Normal. Do not `Dock` the PictureBox nor `Anchor` it to stretch! You can `Dock` or `Anchor` the Panel to your liking.

Comment: accidentally do you have any answer for this post i asked yesterday?

Comment: No I don't. It may help to add the names of the extensions.