# I can't click at last cell in table layout panel

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

i have a problem when i want to click at last cell in my tableLayoutPanel.
When i Run  a program, it looks lika this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tskVt.png)

Next when i click at last cell which i see, everything is ok:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul2my.png)

But when i scroll tableLayoutPanel an click at the last last cell, it isnt mark last cell, but it mark last cell before scrolling TLP.

Here is my code:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        row = 0;
        int verticalOffset = 0;
        foreach (int h in tableLayoutPanel1.GetRowHeights())
        {
            column = 0;
            int horizontalOffset = 0;
            foreach (int w in tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumnWidths())
            {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, w, h);
                if (rectangle.Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    if (column == 1) return;
                    Point cell = new Point(column, row);

                    if (!clickedCells.Contains(cell))
                    {

                        clickedCells.Add(cell);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        clickedCells.Remove(cell);
                    }
                    tableLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("row {0}, column {1} was clicked", row, column));
                    return;
                }
                horizontalOffset += w;
                column++;
            }
            verticalOffset += h;
            row++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems that `e.Location` is an actual on-screen offset from the top-left corner of the panel, while your code calculates offsets in the layoutpanel coordinates. Thus e.Location will never be big enough to point to the rows that are unseen initially. Perhaps there is some property like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.horizontalscrollingoffset(v=vs.110).aspx for panel you use. At worst case you can just put a separate panel into each cell and set its `Tag` property to its location.

Comment: Then you can just handle each panel's click with the same event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the scroll position in your calculations..:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var asp = tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScrollPosition;  // <<===
    row = 0;
    int verticalOffset = asp.Y;                      // <<===
    foreach (int h in tableLayoutPanel1.GetRowHeights())
    {
        column = 0;
        int horizontalOffset = asp.X;                // <<===
        foreach (int w in tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumnWidths())
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(horizontalOffset, verticalOffset, w, h);
            if (rectangle.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                if (column == 1) return;
                Point cell = new Point(column, row);
                if (!clickedCells.Contains(cell))
                {    clickedCells.Add(cell);       }
                else
                {    clickedCells.Remove(cell);    }
                tableLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("row {0}, column {1} was clicked", 
                                row, column));
                return;
            }
            horizontalOffset += w;
            column++;
        }
        verticalOffset += h;
        row++;
    }
}
```